# Android: CheckBoxPreference enable/disable email address inputtype (override default settings)

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-softkeyboard

Hey everyone, I'm trying to make an activity so that when a CheckBox Preference is enabled (true), programmatically the on-screen keyboard InputType will change. I want the user to have the option to turn on/off the keyboard's email address option while keeping the inputType's already set.

Essentially doing the equivalent of changing:

```
android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

to

```
android:inputType="typeAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textmultiLine|textEmailAddress"
```

Preferences.xml

```
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="pref_key_enable_email"
                    android:title="@string/pref_title_enable_email"
                    android:summary="@string/pref_summary_enable_email"
                    android:defaultValue="false" />
```

This is what I have as of now.

```
public void setInputType(int type) {
    boolean showEmail = false;
    // Show the Email keyboard if the pref_key_enable_email preference is TRUE
    mTextEditor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.embedded_text_editor);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(prefs.getBoolean("pref_key_enable_email",false)== true){
        showEmail = true;      
            if (showEmail) {
                mTextEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS); w
           } else {
                mTextEditor.getInputType();
                }
            }
```

I've checked the /data/data/myappname/shared_prefs com.myappnamehere.preferences.xml. I at least know that the boolean values *do* change from false to true when the box is checked. It just doesn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider cleaning your code a little bit

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean showEmail = prefs.getBoolean("pref_key_enable_email",false);
mTextEditor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.embedded_text_editor);

if(showEmail) {
    mTextEditor.setInputType( mTextEditor.getInputType() | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
}
```

I'm assuming you have your "default" flags in the xml for your layout:

```
android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes I have those default flags set. But changing the code didn't result in anything different - the inputType still remains the same. Also as a side note the last line needed to have "InputType." added before "TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL", other than that everything was able to be resolved correctly.